# IPv6 Bind failures

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ipv6

I have a server implementation where I need 2 separate sockets - 1 IPv4 socket socket listening on a particular IPv4 address and server port X, and an IPv6 socket listening on a particular IPv6 address and same server port X. The IPv4 and IPv6 addresses are on the same interface.

```
    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(v4addr);
    sin.sin_port        = htons(tcp_port);
```

I am using evconnlistener_new_bind to create ipv4 socket and bind to it.
For IPv6 listener, the code is as below.

```
    memset(&sin6, 0, sizeof(sin6));
    sin6.sin6_family      = AF_INET6;
    memcpy(sin6.sin6_addr.s6_addr, v6addr_bytes, IPV6_ADDR_LEN);
    sin6.sin6_port        = htons(tcp_port);

    fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    evutil_make_socket_nonblocking(fd)
    setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (void*)&on, sizeof(on))
    setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_V6ONLY, (void*)&on, sizeof(on))
    evutil_make_listen_socket_reuseable(fd)   /* Libevent call to set SO_REUSEADDR */
    evutil_make_socket_nonblocking(fd)        /* Libevent call to set fd non-blocking */ 
    bind(fd, (const struct sockaddr *)&sin6, sizeof(sin6))
```

As I bind my fd to the particular ipv6 address, I see a bind failure intermittently.

bind v6 failed sin6 3ffe::a00:513 - errno 99 - Cannot assign requested address

I tried to gdb in, but every time I gdb in, the bind succeeds.

I am not sure why I am seeing this problem. Can someone please help?

Comment: Addreses in `3ffe::/16` are not valid. Use a valid IPv6 address instead.

Comment: My interface has a 3ffe::10.1.14.14/120 address. While creating the socket, the prefix mask has no implications right? And why do you say its an invalid address?

Comment: Because it isn't valid. That netblock was obsoleted years ago. And the fact that it's in use at all indicates that something is horribly wrong with your IPv6 setup. Fix that first.

Comment: It works sometimes! I will try a different addressing scheme. But any pointers as to why its invalid would help me understand better.

Comment: What i meant was - It is not failing all the time. If it was invalid, shouldn't it fail every time?

Comment: @user2636708 Yes, it should fail every time. What makes you think it ever works? Have you tried using the correct address?

Comment: 3ffe::/16 is currently unallocated, but it's not invalid

Comment: @jch It's not invalid _per se_, but it _is_ filtered in a lot of places. See RFC 3701.

Answer (score 1):

By default, after a socket is bound to a TCP port, the port remains reserved for one minute when the socket is closed — this is called the TCP `TIME_WAIT` state.  `TIME_WAIT` avoids some race conditions that could cause data corruption, but it is usually safe to ignore `TIME_WAIT` on the server side.

This is done by setting the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option:

```
int one = 1;
rc = setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(one))
```

Comment: To clearify, a socket enters the `TIME_WAIT` state when the owning app actively closes the socket while it has an established connection (if the remote peer initiates the close, the socket will not enter `TIME_WAIT`). You can then enable `SO_REUSEADDR` on the NEXT socket that you want to bind to the previously bound ip+port.